# FFmpeg - Batch file bulk editing

Tags: batch-file

I have started a huge video project which I am trying to automate. So far, I made good progress, but now I am stuck. I have searched in Google and here, in Stack OverFlow for answers, but can’t find the solution to my problem.

For completion I will explain my full project.

First step of my project is to convert all of my files to `*.mp4` and in the same run burn my logo and website in the video. I do this with this code:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test\Overlay.png" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128k "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

After that, I will place all the video files in their relevant subfolder. This way I have almost a hundred subfolders, with 2 or 3 files in them. Per submap I want a video with an intro (not in the submap) the video’s in the submap, and an outro (not in the submap).
I can do the above with this code:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i intro.mp4 -i mylist.txt -outro.png -c copy total.mp4
```

To automate everything, I have this code to make a `mylist.txt` file per subfolder:

```
>output.txt (
echo C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test\vast\intro.mp4
(for %%i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%%i')
echo C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test\vast\outro.mp4
)
```

Now the only thing which I have to do is automate the following code:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i intro.mp4 -i mylist.txt -outro.png -c copy total.mp4
```

to go through all the subfolders.

I have made this code:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test" %%F IN (.) DO (
    > %%F\output.txt (
        echo "C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test\vast\intro.mp4"
        (for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
            @echo file '%%i'
        ))
        echo "C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test\vast\outro.mp4"
    )
)
```

This codes provides me with a `mylist.txt` file in every subfolder, but the content is not what I want. It takes the content of the parentmap instead of the subfolders. I have a strong feeling that somewhere in this code I have to make another `FOR /R` but I can’t make it work.

Does someone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FOR /R` will iterate the folders but you try to iterate the `*.mp4` files without referring to the currently processed (sub)folder.

```
@Echo off
Set "Base=C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test"
Set "Ext=*.mp4"

FOR /R "%Base%" %%F IN (.) DO (
    PushD "%%F"
    if exist "%Ext%" (
        > "%%~fF\output.txt" (
            echo "%Base%\vast\intro.mp4"
            For %%I in (%Ext%) do @echo file '%%~fI'
            echo "%Base%\vast\outro.mp4"
        )
        Echo created "%%~fF\output.txt"
    )
    PopD
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. With your code i get an output.txt file in all my submaps but the content is not as i expected. It look likes this: `C:\Users\PC03\Desktop\Video test\test1>() 
MVI_5836.mp4`

The problem is in the `>()`. When i place an `echo %%F` in my code and check the results in the CMD i see there is a only a point instead of the `>()`. 

I believe it is somewhere in the `For /R` but i can't find it. I read the commentation on this page [link] (https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) but cant find any comments about it.

Comment: Also the filename being on another row then the paht in the output.txt file is something i don't understand. I just don't see why or where the code is giving that command. Many thanks for your help so far!

Comment: See revised batch. I inserted the if exist to avoid output.xt files being generated in folders without `*.mp4` files.